# Replacing ### with integers

Tags: c#

By using RegEx, or String.Replace, I need to replace any number of consecutive #'s (with the appropriate number of leading 0's) with an integer. I know I can search for # in the string, get the First and Last index, Last-First for the length, then replace with String.Replace.  I was hoping someone would have a faster, and more slick answer.

Method header would be:

```
string ReplaceHashtagsWithInt(string input, int integer)
```

Examples:

Input -> "String####_Hi##", 2

Output -> "String0002_Hi02"

Input -> "String####_Hi##", 123

Output -> "String0123_Hi123"

Comment: Can you post the code for what you have tried, and where it seems to not be working as expected?

Comment: Searching for "#" in string is probably the fastest way of doing that.

Comment: Leverage String.Format(), you'll want to replace a run of ### by {0:000}, ensuring that the number of 0's matches the number of #'s.  Takes ~8 lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static class Testing
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ReplaceHashtagsWithInt("String####_Hi##", 2);
        ReplaceHashtagsWithInt("String####_Hi###", 123);
        ReplaceHashtagsWithInt("String####_Hi#######", 123);
    }

    public static string ReplaceHashtagsWithInt(string input, int integer)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("#+");

        var matches = regex.Matches(input).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
        Array.Sort(matches);
        Array.Reverse(matches);

        foreach (string match in matches)
        {
            Regex r = new Regex(match);
            string zeroes = new string('0', match.Length - integer.ToString().Length) + integer;
            input = r.Replace(input, zeroes);
        }

        return input;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would fail if it found a smaller group before a larger group - thus `"### - ####", 2` would become `002 - 002#` https://dotnetfiddle.net/hG2aGp

Comment: @Aravol, nice catch.

Comment: change `r.Replace(input, zeroes);` to `r.Replace(input, zeroes, 1, match.Index);` and do safeguard when `match.Length - integer.ToString().Length` < 0 to fix your solution

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static class Testing
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ReplaceHashtagsWithInt("###_####_#", 1));
        Console.WriteLine(ReplaceHashtagsWithInt("###_####_#", 23));
        Console.WriteLine(ReplaceHashtagsWithInt("###_####_#", 456));
        Console.WriteLine(ReplaceHashtagsWithInt("###_####_#", 7890));
        Console.WriteLine(ReplaceHashtagsWithInt("###_####_#", 78901));
    }

    public static string ReplaceHashtagsWithInt(string input, int integer)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("#+");

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(input);
        int allig = 0;      

        for(Match match = regex.Match(input);match.Success;match = match.NextMatch())        
        {

            string num = integer.ToString();

            if(num.Length<=match.Length)
                for(int i=0;i<match.Length;i++)
                {
                    if(i<match.Length-num.Length)
                        output[match.Index+i+allig] = '0';
                    else
                        output[match.Index+i+allig] = num[i-match.Length+num.Length];
                }
            else
            {
                output.Remove(match.Index+allig,match.Length);
                output.Insert(match.Index+allig,num);
                allig+=num.Length-match.Length;
            }
        }

        return output.ToString();
    }
}
```